# Исходный код Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Где можно найти исходный код именно самой Intellij IDEA? Конкретно код самой IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Исходники комунити-версии](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) в официальном репозитории компании и  [архивы исходников](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Download) на офф.сайте